# Representation of an inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I'm facing the following problem:

Let $ K $ be a field of characteristic not equal to $ 2 $. Prove that if $ \alpha \in K $ is representable as $ x^2 - ay^2 $, then so is $ \alpha^{-1} $

Well, I approached it in two ways:

a) Tried to solve $ (x^2 - ay^2)(u^2 - av^2) = 1 $ for $ v ~\text{and} ~ u$;

b) Tried to represent $(x^2 - a y^2)^{-1}$ as $\frac{1}{x^2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\left( \frac{y^2}{x^2}\right)^n$

But neither has lead me nowhere close to the solution.

I'd appreciate some help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\alpha = x^2 -a y^2$, then 
$$\alpha^{-1} = \alpha\cdot\frac{1}{\alpha^2} = \frac{1}{\alpha^2}(x^2-ay^2).$$
Presumably you can take it from there.

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Thanks!